# Differences in meaning between using parenthetical comments and not

Tags: grammar, commas, parentheticals

What are the differences between using parenthetical comments and not?

Such as if you have this sentence :

> Calhoun's ambition,  to become a goalie in professional soccer,  is within his reach.

Compared to :

> > Calhoun's ambition to become a goalie in professional soccer is within his reach.

It's an english task of mine.. Have searched for it with no satisfying result on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence suggests that Calhoun only has one ambition, and the parenthetical phrase defines what it is. It's similar to:

> Calhoun's ambition is to become a goalie in professional soccer, and this is within his reach.

The second sentence could be used when he has multiple ambitions, but we're only making a statement about the specific one of becoming a goalie. "to become a goalie" is a subordinate clause that specifies which ambition is being referred to, rather than defining what it is.